# What is the song that plays when Muramasa charges at Ichigo?

Tags: bleach

I heard several times but can't find the song. It plays in season 13 in episode 253, starting around 9:58, right when Muramasa charges at Ichigo after turning into a hollow.

Answer (score 1):

It's **Shadow's Masquerade**.

The first usage of the soundtrack is in episode 88 of the Season 4: Bount arc. The music itself is the track #16 from [BLEACH Original Soundtrack 2](http://vgmdb.net/album/22885).